# When executed, your code modified memory in a way that was illegal

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and am getting this error when I try and submit to myprogramminglab:

> When executed, your code modified memory in a way that was illegal. Common causes for this problem include array indexing errors and pointer operation (*) errors.

What do I need to change to make it run correctly? Thanks. I am not meant to define the class, just the program that uses it.

> a program that uses the Date class you defined in 7.1a. The program prompts "date information: " and then reads three integers: the day of month. the month and the year. The program then prints the date three times, each time on a line by itself. The first time the date is in numerical format, the second in month-first format, and the third time in date first format.

Here is one sample run:

```
date information: 15 3 2014
3/15/2014
March 15, 2014
15 March 2014
```

*****Note: Do not define the class here-- just write the program that uses it. *****

The code that keeps getting an error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
class date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
public:
    date (int month = 1, int day = 1, int year = 2001)
    {
        date::month = month;
        date::day = day;
        date::year = year;
    };
             
    void showDate();
    ~date(){}
};
         
void date::showDate(){
    cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;
}
    
int main()
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    
    string monthName[12] = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
    "August","September","October","November","December"};

    cout << "date information: ";
    cin >> day >> month >> year;
    
    date newDate(month, day, year);
    newDate.showDate();
    cout << monthName[month-1]<< " " << day << ", " << year << endl;
    cout << day << " " << monthName[month-1] << " " << year << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you change `date::month` to just `month` (same for day/year)? That might help out.

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to install a compiler and debugger on your own machine. It's far from the last time this will happen to you.

Comment: The two instances of `monthName[month-1]` at the bottom of the program look like possible culprits; for example if `month` is set equal to `0`, then `month-1` would evaluate to `-1` and therefore the expression would be equivalent to `monthName[-1]` which would invoke undefined behavior (due to out-of-bounds array indexing)

Comment: Is the code expected to have error checking? What is it supposed to do if the date is illegal? Without knowing what the code is supposed to do, it's hard for us to tell whether or not it does what it is supposed to.

Comment: @mattlangford: Or `this->month` if they want to be explicit about the distinction between the instance attributes and the constructor arguments. Better, use initializers instead of code in the body of the constructor, e.g. `date (int month = 1, int day = 1, int year = 2001) : month(month), day(day), year(year) {}`, and avoid writing each field twice. Probably not the cause of the problem though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz From a previous question:

For the purposes of this exercise, the following are invalid values:
For day of month: any value less than 1 or greater than 31 (so February 30 or April 31 would be acceptable)
For month: any value less than 1 or greater than 12
For year: any value less than 0

Comment: @Learning well, don't you think that is something your code should be validating before using the values the user enters?

Comment: @Learning What does that mean though? Does that mean that your code does not have to handle them? Or do you have to do something specific when you get an "invalid value"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz honestly, I am unsure, this is my first c++ class and my teacher isn't very good at getting back to me. 

Obviously I am confused at both the question and the comments.

Comment: If you don't know if you should validate user inputs, err on the side of caution and validate the inputs. Very good habit to get into early. Potential mistakes you don't look for and handle tend to turn into bugs later.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem i see with your solution is in the last lines

```
 cout << monthName[month-1]<< " " << day << ", " << year << endl;
 cout << day << " " << monthName[month-1] << " " << year << endl;
```

a wrong input from user, say the month being 15 ,would be out of bounds from the array you have right now as it will try and access monthName[14] which is not there, hence you receive **Segmentation Fault**